# 1 to many with composite key as primary key

Tags: entity-framework-core

I tried many different examples here, but i can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong.

I have a table with a history table to it. I have removed many of the fields to make it easier to watch. After my migration it works fine if i watch in PHPMyAdmin and watch the primaryKey there.

I want to be able to go context.ProductArtifactDocumentState.Histories so i can get all linked histories.

DBContext

```
    //Composite Key
    builder.Entity<ProductArtifactDocumentStateHistory>()
        .HasKey(k => new { k.Version, k.ProductArtifactDocumentStateId});
```

Table

```
[Table("ProductArtifactDocumentsState")]
    public partial class ProductArtifactDocumentState : BaseEntity
    {    
        public virtual ICollection<ProductArtifactDocumentStateHistory> ProductArtifactDocumentStateHistories { get; set; }
    }
```

History Table

```
[Table("ProductArtifactDocumentsState_History")]
    public partial class ProductArtifactDocumentStateHistory
    {
        [Column("ProductArtifactDocumentStateId")]
        public int ProductArtifactDocumentStateId { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductArtifactDocumentState ProductArtifactDocumentState { get; set; }
        public int Version { get; set; }        
    }
```

The error i get:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'ProductArtifactDocumentStateHistory' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need all this headache? Are you trying to save 2 bytes on a primary key? But after this all your ef code will be a nightmare. Just add Id field

```
 public partial class ProductArtifactDocumentStateHistory
    {
       [Key]
       public int Id {get; set;}

      .....
    }
```